# Trouble using areas, not sure if something wrong with routing or web.config settings

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

Question is described by the steps below.

1. Create a new ASP.NET MVC3 Web Application using Internet Application Template.
2. Decorate HomeController class with Authorize.
3. Run the application, It basically takes you http://localhost: 51578/Account/LogOn?ReturnUrl=%2F  Everything good so far.

Let’s customize a couple of things in this project.

1. Add an area named “Login” in this solution and move AccountController.cs, AccountModel.cs and whole Account folder under Viewer into appropriate folder under this Area named Login.
2. Run the application now and you will get following error

Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

Exception Details: System.InvalidOperationException: The view 'LogOn' or its master was not found or no view engine supports the searched locations. The following locations were searched:
~/Views/Account/LogOn.aspx
~/Views/Account/LogOn.ascx
~/Views/Shared/LogOn.aspx
~/Views/Shared/LogOn.ascx
~/Views/Account/LogOn.cshtml
~/Views/Account/LogOn.vbhtml
~/Views/Shared/LogOn.cshtml
~/Views/Shared/LogOn.vbhtml

Do I need to modify anything in the web.config or in routing to make this work?

Answer (score 1):

The authorize attribute is redirecting you to the `LogOn` page which can't be found in the View folder that is outside the `Login` area. If you move the `HomeController` in the Login area and in LoginRegisterArea you add a valid route to the home controller it will work.

I tried to do what you wanted, but the only solution I found was to have the controllers you want to authorize and the LogOn view in the same place. The solution I previously mentioned about keeping the controller and the LogOn view separate deosn't work.

Maybe someone can find a solution that accomplishes what you really want.

Comment: Well that's the whole point here, I wanted to move LogOn related code in a separate area for better code organization while keeping other stuff separate ( and may add in another Area or something in future).

Comment: Thanks Bogdan for suggestion but when I modify LoginAreaRegistration, I get following error  Server Error in '/' Application. Not sure what I need to modify in the AccountController though. Any ideas? 
The resource cannot be found. 
Description: HTTP 404. The resource you are looking for (or one of its dependencies) could have been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.  Please review the following URL and make sure that it is spelled correctly.